# Utility of PINSR[B/D/Q] (using GCC C Vector Extensions)

Tags: gcc, assembly, vectorization

There are some slides [here](http://www.whatsacreel.net76.net/slides/asmtute57.pdf) that discuss these SSE4.1 instructions, but I am still not sure what they're good for when using GCC's vector types.

When I create a vector type in GCC C, in the following way:

```
typedef char v16s8 __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
v16s8 a = {2,-1,3,4,2,-3,1,5,6,-3,1,0,2,3,-4,2};
int putin = 99;
```

And then I decide to put in "putin" using one of these two methods:

```
test[1] = putin;
test = __builtin_ia32_vec_set_v16qi (test, putin, 1);
```

The top command generates one single movb instruction, but the second generates a movdqa, then the pinsrb, then movaps, then movdqa.

Would it be correct to assume the pinsrb command is only useful when you wish to preserve the original vector **and** create a new one with the byte changed, therefore accomplishing 2 things (duplication and element insertion) in one command?

Another hypothesis: my test code is worthless because GCC is really just putting the byte in its internal type and never loading it back into the original xmm register. But I don't know how best to test this either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value is still in memory, the compiler may very well decide to use simple `mov`. You should play around to see what happens if it's already in a register. Also don't forget to enable optimizations, not to mention the relevant SSE instruction set (`-msse4.1`).

Given this code (next time please post complete code yourself, too):

```
typedef char v16s8 __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
void foo(v16s8* arg)
{
    v16s8 test = {2,-1,3,4,2,-3,1,5,6,-3,1,0,2,3,-4,2};
    int putin = 99;
    test[1] = putin;
    *arg = test;
}
```

gcc 5.2 with `-O2 -msse4.1` produces:

```
movdqa  .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
movl    $99, %eax
pinsrb  $1, %eax, %xmm0
movaps  %xmm0, (%rdi)
ret
```

(See using [gcc explorer](http://goo.gl/dbSuS2)).

Comment: Excellent. I was using gcc 4.6 (C mode, not C++), which wasn't producing PINSRB even in the code you provided. Starting with GCC 4.7, it does produce pinsrb. Thanks to your link, I was able to figure this out. Great sleuthing, friend. I'm sure this will help others (especially those considering using this instruction directly as an intrinsic rather than letting the compiler work its magic).